# C++ Template Class Initialization in Condition Statements

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to allow the user to choose if the template is a int, double, or string. But with my method there is an inherit problem, since I'm using If-statements to initialize the class template object, the compiler will throw an error whenever I want to make a method call.

```
template<class T>
class foo {
    private:
        int bar
    public:
        void setBar(int newBar);

};
template<class T>
void foo<T>::setBar(int newBar) {
    bar = newBar;
}
int main() {
    int inputType;
    cout << endl << "1 for integer, 2 for double, 3 for strings." << endl <<
            "What kind of data do you wish to enter?(1-3): ";
    cin >> inputType;
    if(inputType == 1) {
        foo<int> v1;
    } else if(inputType == 2) {
        foo<double> v1;
    } else if(inputType == 3) {
        foo<string> v1;
    } else {
        cout << "Error - Please enter in a proper #: ";
    }
    //Compiler Error
    v1.setBar(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Since I'm doing it this way, I get an error saying "v1 was not delcared in this scope" whenever i try to call `setBar()`. How do I get past this and allow the user to choose AND allow for method calls? I know if I weren't using templates I could just declare it before the if-statements, but with templates the compiler demands I tell it what type I want first. 
Thanks!

Comment: if(inputType == 1) {
        foo<int> v1;
    }
by seeing your code i found that variable v1 is defined in the scope of if. Try using global variables and call the function on variable on user choice. i-e declare different global  variables for both int and double (say foo<int> ival foo<double> dval) and on choice of user call function (dval.setbar(3). regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done as you are attempting it. The first problem being that the different variables `v1` are defined in scopes that don't include the later use. There are different workarounds that can be taken, of which the first two that come to mind are:

- Reorder the code so that the code at the end of main is implemented in a templated function, call that function with different arguments depending on the code path

Example

```
template <typename T>
void process() {
   foo<T> v1;
   v1.setBar(3);
}
int main() {
  // …
  switch (input) {
  case 1: process<int>(); break;
  case 2: process<double>(); break;
  default: process<string>(); break;
  };
}
```

- Use dynamic polymorphism. Implement a base type with a virtual interface, instantiate one of the templates (that inherit from the interface type) inside the different branches and set a pointer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I understand what I have to do now.

Comment: Yep, it's working out great for me. Using a separate template process was a really good idea, thanks again!